# No se utilizar func_get_args (). Necesito implementarla en el código de abajo para hacer un ejercicio. Gracias de antemano

Tags: php, html, funciones

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Formulari interactiu amb if-else</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Ciutat preferida</h2>
    <?php
// Si no s'ha premut el botó, es va al formulari inicial
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="ex4.3.php">
        <p>Introdueixi la seva informació:</p>
        Ciutat: <input type="text" name="ciutat" />
        Mes: <input type="text" name="mes" />
        Any: <input type="text" name="any" />
        <p>Si us plau, seleccioni quin tipus de temps metereològic heu experimentat.
            <br />Escolliu el que toqui. </p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="assolellat" />Assolellat<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="núvols" />Núvols<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="pluja" />Pluja<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="calamarsa" />Calamarsa<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="aiguaneu" />Aiguaneu<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="neu" />Neu<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="vent" />Vent<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="fred" />Fred<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="calor" />Calor<br />
        <p />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Endavant" />
    </form>
    <?php
// Si s'ha premut el botó es processa l'entrada
} else {
    //Es recull el valor de la cadena 'ciutat'
    $ciutat = $_POST['ciutat'];
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    $any = $_POST['any'];

    echo "A $ciutat al mes de $mes de l'any $any, es va observar que el temps era següent:";
    echo "\n<ul>\n";
    foreach ($_POST['tempsMeteo'] as $valor) {
        echo "<li>$valor</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya me he respondido a mi pregunta tengo el código resuelto. Adjunto una solución a otro ejercicio que va de la misma tónica para quien le interese.

```html
<html>

 

<head>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <title>Formulari interactiu amb if-else</title>

</head>

 

<body>

    <h2>Ciutat preferida</h2>

    <?php

// Si no s'ha premut el botó, es va al formulari inicial

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">

        <p>Introdueixi la seva informació:</p>

        Ciutat: <input type="text" name="ciutat" />

        Mes: <input type="text" name="mes" />

        Any: <input type="text" name="any" />

        <p>Si us plau, seleccioni quin tipus de temps metereològic heu experimentat.

            <br />Escolliu el que toqui. </p>

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="assolellat" />Assolellat<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="núvols" />Núvols<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="pluja" />Pluja<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="calamarsa" />Calamarsa<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="aiguaneu" />Aiguaneu<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="neu" />Neu<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="vent" />Vent<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="fred" />Fred<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="calor" />Calor<br />
  
   <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="humitat" />Humitat<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="boira" />Boira<br />

        <p />
  
  
        Nou requeriment de dades a l usuari
            <p>Alguna cosa més? Si us plau introdueix les noves condicions metereològiques,
            separades per comes.</p>
            <input type="text" name="textUsuari" size="60" /><p />  

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Endavant" />

    </form>

    <?php

// Si s'ha premut el botó es processa l'entrada

} else {

    //Es recull el valor de la cadena 'ciutat'

    $ciutat = $_POST['ciutat'];

    $mes = $_POST['mes'];

    $any = $_POST['any'];

 

    echo "A $ciutat al mes de $mes de l'any $any, es va observar que el temps era el següent:";

    
 
 $recollida = $_POST['textUsuari'];
 $listaRecollida = explode(",",$recollida);
 
 function llistaHo($llista1,$llista2){
  $dim = count($llista1)-1;
  $i = 1;
   foreach($llista2 as $valor){
    $llista1[$dim + $i] = $valor;
    $i = $i +1 ;
   }
  return $llista1;
 }
 
 
 
 
 $resultado = llistaHo($_POST['tempsMeteo'], $listaRecollida);
 //print_r($resultado);
 
 echo "\n<ul>\n";
 foreach ($resultado as $valor) {

        echo "<li>$valor</li>\n";

    }
 echo "</ul>";

 

    

}

?>

</body>

 

</html>
```

```html
<html>

 

<head>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <title>Formulari interactiu amb if-else</title>

</head>

 

<body>

    <h2>Ciutat preferida</h2>

    <?php

// Si no s'ha premut el botó, es va al formulari inicial

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">

        <p>Introdueixi la seva informació:</p>

        Ciutat: <input type="text" name="ciutat" />

        Mes: <input type="text" name="mes" />

        Any: <input type="text" name="any" />

        <p>Si us plau, seleccioni quin tipus de temps metereològic heu experimentat.

            <br />Escolliu el que toqui. </p>

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="assolellat" />Assolellat<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="núvols" />Núvols<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="pluja" />Pluja<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="calamarsa" />Calamarsa<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="aiguaneu" />Aiguaneu<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="neu" />Neu<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="vent" />Vent<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="fred" />Fred<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="tempsMeteo[]" value="calor" />Calor<br />

        <p />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Endavant" />

    </form>

    <?php

// Si s'ha premut el botó es processa l'entrada

} else {

    //Es recull el valor de la cadena 'ciutat'

    $ciutat = $_POST['ciutat'];

    $mes = $_POST['mes'];

    $any = $_POST['any'];

 

    echo "A $ciutat al mes de $mes de l'any $any, es va observar que el temps era següent:";


 

    function botSel()

    {
  echo "\n<ul>\n";
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
     

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arg_list[0]); $i++) {

            echo "<br>".$arg_list[0][$i]."\n";

        }
      echo "</ul>";


    }


    botSel($_POST["tempsMeteo"]);

}

?>

</body>

 

</html>
```